# Poincaré-Bendixson theorem and the Sinai Billiard

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, chaos-theory, hamilton-equations

One of the conclusion of the [Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bendixson_theorem#Discussion) is that in planar dynamical systems chaotic motion could not arise.
But in the [Sinai Billiard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_billiards) trajectories in fact are chaotic...how is this possible?

Comment: are those billiards *differentiable* dynamical systems as required by the theorem?

Comment: Grazie @AlessandroCodenotti. I think the billiards are differentiable only between collisions - so the answer is no. Am I right?

Comment: The real problem is that the phase space of a two-dimensional billiard is not two-dimensional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alessandro's remark is a red herring. True, Sinai billiard flows are not differentiable, but that's not the main issue.

The phase space of the billiard flow is the space of couples $(x,v)$, where $x$ belongs to the billiard and $v$ is a unit speed vector. Hence you have $3$ degrees of freedom, so the billiard flow acts on a $3$-dimensional space. Obviously Poincaré-Bendixon does not apply.

(there are further issues about the differentiability of the system and the topology of the phase space, but they seem secondary to me).

Comment: Good point, I hadn't noticed but that's definitely a far bigger issue!